# Outer query value is not able use in inner query

Tags: mysql, oracle, salesforce, mule, mule-component

```
SELECT 
    (select Email from Contact where AccountId = Account.Id),
    Id,
    BillingCity,
     BillingCountry,
     BillingPostalCode,
     BillingState,
     BillingStreet,
     Name,
     Phone 
FROM Account
 where 
 LastModifiedDate < #[flowVars['timestamp']]
```

Problem here is I am not able to get the Email which is present in the sub query based on the **Id** of current iteration. Can you please help on this

Comment: What do you mean by not able? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want get Email based on condition of Contact.AccountId=Account.Id for each row in the output

Comment: Join Contact table with Account table and then use it.

Comment: can you please provide use case of me which i posted

Comment: Please share a snapshot of dataset of the 2 tables as well. Any specific reason you don't want to use joins?

Comment: The solution will also depend on which database you are using. Is the question applicable to `mysql` or `oracle`? Please remove tags which are not applicable to the question.

Comment: As per above query I don't have direct Email field in Account table Due to that I am getting email id based on filter condition is Contact.AccountId=Account.Id  to get the email. Note: I need to get the email of each row w.r.t to its Id

Comment: It is related to salesforce query

Comment: what error message you getting?

Comment: [MalformedQueryFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='MALFORMED_QUERY'
 exceptionMessage='
FROM Contact where AccountId = Account.Id) as email ,BillingCity
                              ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:52
Bind variables only allowed in Apex code'
 extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
]
 row='1'
 column='52'
]
]

Comment: Adove is error which i am getting

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are running the query, and how you are accessing the result, but if you are doing it in a place that does not give you the result dynamically, meaning that you try to access the columns by expected name, i.e. trying to get the "email" column somehow, then you need to fix a small issue in the query.

You need to add the `AS` operator to give your subquery a meaningful name like `email` like so:

```
... 
(select Email from Contact where AccountId = Account.Id) as email, 
...
```

See fiddle here for working example: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jbecUHC6eeWgV3JWVHgbK/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the scalar sub-query and just put a join to the CONTACT table instead. The following assumes that the CONTACT table is an optional relationship.

```
SELECT 
    con.email,
    acct.Id,
    acct.BillingCity,
    acct.BillingCountry,
    acct.BillingPostalCode,
    acct.BillingState,
    acct.BillingStreet,
    acct.Name,
    acct.Phone 
FROM account acct
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     contact con ON con.account_id = acct.account_id
WHERE acct.LastModifiedDate < #[flowVars['timestamp']]
```